# How can you detect which which WordPress FSE template is being used by a page?

Tags: php, wordpress

With the latest WordPress Full-Site Editor, `get_page_template_slug()` no longer returns the template used by the page. What PHP function would determine which template is being used by a page?

Comment: I don't use FSE but this thread https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56394 has some possible suggestions that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can use `locate_block_template()` instead of `get_page_template()` for block-based themes. Reference: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56394